# Bigquery job suddenly started failing from today due to coorelated subquery

Tags: google-bigquery

My Bigquery job which was executing fine until yesterday started failing due to the below error

Error:- Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN

Query:-

```
with result as (
  select
    *
  from
  (
    select * from `project.dataset_stage.=non_split_daily_temp`
    union all
    select * from `project.dataset_stage.split_daily_temp`
  )
)
select
  *
from
  result final
where
  not (
    exists
    (
      select
        1
      from
        `project.dataset.bqt_sls_cust_xref` target
      where
        final.sls_dte = target.sls_dte and
        final.rgs_id = target.rgs_id and
    ) and
    unlinked = 'Y' and
   cardmatched = 'Y'
  }
```

Can someone please assist me on this, i would like to know reason for sudden break of this and how to fix this issue permanently.

Comment: Can you provide sample data from your tables?
Also, is `project.dataset.bqt_sls_cust_xref` table unique for every sls_dte, str_id and rgs_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestion.

We figured out the reason for the cause of the issue ,below is the reason

When one writes correlated subquery like

`select T2.col, (select count(*) from T1 where T1.col = T2.col) from T2`

Technically SQL text implies that subquery needs to be re-executed for every row from T2.
If T2 has billion rows then we would need to scan T1 billion times. That would take forever and query would never finish.

The cost of executing query dropped from O(size T1 * size T2) to O(size T1 + size T2) if implemented as below

```
with t as (select primary_key, col from T2)
select any_value(t.col), count(*)
from t
left join T1 on T1.col = t.col
group by t.primary_key
```

BigQuery errors out if it can't find a way to optimize correlated subquery into linear cost O(size T1 + size T2).

We have plenty of patterns that we recognize and we rewrite for correlated subqueries but apparently new view definition made subquery too complex and query optimizer was unable find a way to run it in linear complexity algorithm.

Probably google will fix the issue by identifying the better algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it suddenly broke, but seemingly, your query can be rewritten with `OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
with result as (
  select
    *
  from
  (
    select * from `project.dataset_stage.=non_split_daily_temp`
    union all
    select * from `project.dataset_stage.split_daily_temp`
  )
)
select
  *
from
  result final LEFT OUTER JOIN `project.dataset.bqt_sls_cust_xref` target
                          ON final.sls_dte = target.sls_dte and
                             final.str_id = target.str_id and
                             final.rgs_id = target.rgs_id
where
    target.<id_column> IS NULL AND -- No join found, equivalent to NOT (HAVING (<correlected sub-query>)) 
    was_unlinked_run = 'Y' and
    is_card_matched = 'Y'
  )
```